# How do you split a time series into separate, even segments?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals, fft

I want to perform a manual short time fourier transform. I have a simple time series in the form of a cosine wave. I want to perform a short time fourier transform by splitting up the time series into a number of evenly spaced segments that include overlap... how do i do that?

this is my time series:

```
fs = 10e3 # Sampling frequency
N = 1e5 # Number of samples
time = np.arange(N) / fs
x = np.cos(5*time) # Some random audio wave
# x.shape gives (100000,)
```

How do i split into say, 10 evenly spaced segments?

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the expected output?

Comment: the term to lookup is called window or windowing ... each set of samples is a window ... you can write a loop to define a window with start and end index then slide this window a tad and repeat in next loop iteration until you have slide off the end of source elements ... often its more productive to roll you own than take the time to find a library

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this.

```
import numpy as np

def get_windows(n, Mt, olap):
    # Split a signal of length n into olap% overlapping windows each containing Mt terms 
    ists = []
    ieds = []

    ist = 0
    while 1:
        ied = ist + Mt
        if ied > n:
            break
        ists.append(ist)
        ieds.append(ied)
        ist += int(Mt * (1 - olap/100))
    return ists, ieds

n = 100
x = np.arange(n)

ists, ieds = get_windows(n, Mt=20, olap=50) # windows of length 20 and 50% overlap
for ist, ied in zip(ists, ieds):
    print(x[ist:ied])
```

result:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
[20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
[30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
[40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
[50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
[60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
[70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
[80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
```

If your data is relatively small and you are comfortable with storing all the windows in RAM, then you can continue as follows:

```
X = np.array([x[ist:ied] for ist, ied in zip(ists, ieds)]) 
# X.shape is (nwindows, Mt)
```

By doing this, you can generate `W` a windowing function (e.g. Hanning window) as a 1D array of shape (Mt, ), so that `W*X` will broadcast in a way so that `W` applies to each window in `X`.

I just noticed that the term "window" is used with two meanings in this context. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i have one question though about saving the list as split up arrays? how do you store the split up data? because i am trying to perform a short time fourier transform on it, and i would like to first apply a tapering function etc. thanks!